# npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4 ,@types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to Deploy my application through Netlify and I keep getting the same error. :

```
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR! Found: @types/react@18.2.55
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"*" from @material-ui/types@5.1.0
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/types
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     @material-ui/types@"5.1.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/core
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!       @material-ui/core@"^4.9.10" from the root project
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!       2 more (@material-ui/icons, @material-ui/lab)
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     @material-ui/types@"5.1.0" from @material-ui/styles@4.11.5
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/styles
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!       @material-ui/styles@"^4.11.5" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!       node_modules/@material-ui/core
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!         @material-ui/core@"^4.9.10" from the root project
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!         2 more (@material-ui/icons, @material-ui/lab)
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/base@5.0.0-beta.36
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/base
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     @mui/base@"5.0.0-beta.36" from @mui/lab@5.0.0-alpha.165
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/lab
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!       @mui/lab@"^5.0.0-alpha.164" from the root project
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     @mui/base@"5.0.0-beta.36" from @mui/material@5.15.10
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!       @mui/material@"^5.15.10" from the root project
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!       2 more (@mui/icons-material, @mui/lab)
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!   11 more (@mui/icons-material, @mui/lab, @mui/material, ...)
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR! peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.9.10" from the root project
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!   peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/icons
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     @material-ui/icons@"^4.9.1" from the root project
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!   1 more (@material-ui/lab)
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @types/react@17.0.75
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.9.10" from the root project
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/icons
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!       @material-ui/icons@"^4.9.1" from the root project
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!     1 more (@material-ui/lab)
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR!
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
1:03:44 PM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried to change to version 17 and 16 of React and I also tried to change MUI version but it didn't help.